# Random Multiple Lines From TXT File

Tags: php

How do I generate random Lines From text file

**lines.txt**

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
ccccccccc
ddddddddd
eeeeeeeee
```

Here is what I tried

**Random.php**

```
<?php $lines = file("lines.txt");echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];?>
```

The Random Result :

```
ccccccccc
```

**I want like this :**

```
aaaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbbb|ccccccccc|ddddddddd|eeeeeeeee
```

.

```
ccccccccc|ddddddddd|aaaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbbb|eeeeeeeee
```

Comment: @jhpratt i tried to random multiple lines from .txt in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once red from file, use shuffle function to randomize the array then implode function to output the way you want it (Delimited by | )

```
<?php
$lines = file("lines.txt");
shuffle($lines);
echo implode('|', $lines);
?>
```